# Monte Carlo Estimation of $\pi$

Tags: algorithm, montecarlo, pi

When using the Monte Carlo method to estimate $\pi$, we would fit a unit circle into a square, such as:
[image]

I am very confused with the following description for the above circle, which is extracted from https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/estimating-value-pi-using-monte-carlo/:
[image]

Shouldn't the area of the square be $2^2$ since 0 to -1 is 1 and 0 to 1 is another 1?
The same goes to the radius of the circle - isn't it $1$ instead of $\frac{1}{2}$?

Comment: I think you're right, the area of the square is 4 and the area of the circle is pi. By the way, since this isn't a specific programming question, it's more suitable for math.stackexchange.com.

Comment: The text is correct, but the picture doesn't match it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems to be a mistake of the author. I am guessing that they hastily interpreted the image as a plot with the bottom left corner as (0,0) instead of (-1, -1). Another possibility is that the image changed without changing the description.

But as Robert pointed out, you are right, but keep in mind that their calculation for the area of the square is also wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Objectively speaking you are right. The radius of the circle is of length 1 and each side of the square is of length 2. I think the image is not scaled properly. The moral of the story is having this relationship between the areas:

Area_of_circle/Area_of_square = pi/4

Also I'd recommend taking a look at the on policy monte carlo control, found in Rich Sutton's Reinforcement Learning book:

[image]

this nicely generalized the algorithm for estimating the optimal policy using an epsilon soft policy to select the greedy action.